# How can I set some default values to a column in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

So i have a table in my rails webapp that looks like this in the "db/schema.rb" file:

```
create_table "checks", force: cascade do |t|
  t.text "name"
  t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  t.string "status", default: "pending", null: false
end
```

My question is, how i can set three "default" values to status. I only want the values "pending", "scheduled" and "runnin" to be able so get set as a value of "status".

I somehow didn't find something about that. Only to set one default value but that is not what i want.

Would really appreciate a quick answer. Thanks!

Comment: what you want is [enum](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.4.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html)

Comment: You want to use enum fields, and use timestamps instead of creating manually created_at and updated_at fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use model to do it, following is example fo doing. in your migration add following

```
t.integer "status", default: 1, null: false
```

Now in your modle `app/models/checks.rb` put following codes

```
  STATUS = {
    pending: 0,
    scheduled: 1,
    runnin: 2
  }.freeze

  enum status: STATUS
```

Now you can also access like following

```
check = Check.first
puts check.status
```

So you are actually saving enum in integer, whose values you define in module. This is one way of doing it.

Comment: I did it like this, just that I changed the integer so a string so I can read the data more easily. For example pending is set to "pending". And also I didnt use freeze. But thank you very much for answering.

Comment: `freeze` just makes variable unchangeable, not needed.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Kamal's answer, you don't have to define the hash and then set the enum. You can pass use an array of symbols there instead.

`enum status: %i[pending scheduled runnin]`

When you can access/view the enum hash with `Check.statuses` which will return
`{pending: 0, scheduled: 1, runnin: 2}` and just like he said:

```
check = Check.first
puts check.status
```

Rails' enum also gives you access to scopes and instance methods.

```
Check.pending # returns ALL pending checks

# if check belongs to any other model....
other = Other.first
other.checks.pending # returning all pending checks that belong to the instance of other model

#boolean checks
check = Check.first
check.pending? # returns true or false if the check has the enum 0

# setting the enum
check = Check.first
check.pending! # sets and saves the check's status as pending
```

And then to set the default, just as Kamal stated

`t.integer, :status, default: 1, null: false, index: true`

As to setting 3 different defaults, you can't. You need to pick one of the enum's values and set that as default as stated above.

When creating a `Check`, you can set the value either with the `!` shown above or in the create params if you want to set it to something other than the default:

```
pending_status = Check.statuses[:pending]
Check.create(status: pending_status)
```

This method is helpful so you don't have to worry about the position of the enums if they happen to change later on in development.

[Rails' enum docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.4.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html)